# 'for' loop in a SaltStack SLS file

Tags: salt-stack

I have a pillar file containing data:

```
zones: 

    ['us-east-1a','us-east-1b']
```

Now I want to apply a loop in one of the sls files. This is what I am trying:

```
{% for zone in salt['pillar.get']('zones') %}<br>
   - {{zone}}<br>
{ %endfor %}
```

But it is throwing an error:

```
Bad Request: Value (['us-west-1a', 'us-west-1b'])
```

Can you please help me with that?

Comment: {% for zone in salt['pillar.get']('zones') %}
- {{zone}}
{ %endfor %}

Comment: Fail to tell the proper story, Not a proper state/pillar format. Too little information.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
zones: 
    - 'us-east-1a'
    - 'us-east-1b'
```